# High_contrast error after 8.4.4

Tags: 8

After the 8.8.4 update I am getting the following error when I try to clear caches:

> Circular reference detected for service "theme_handler", path: "twig -> twig.loader.filesystem -> theme_handler -> config.factory -> high_contrast.overrider -> theme.manager
>     -> theme.negotiator -> access_check.theme".

Uninstalling the high_contrast module fixes the issue, but I would prefer to keep using it for accessibility purposes.

I can't find any relevant bugs on the module [webpage](https://www.drupal.org/project/high_contrast)

Is anyone else having this issue or is something else going on?

Comment: Looks like a bug in that module. I'd report it in the module issue queue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug report to a third-party dependency hosted on drupal.org or elsewhere and must be reported to its issue queue over there to track issues at a single place, not here.